# Struggling to see why reverse sort doesnt take into account 100

Tags: python, sorting, reverse

I am importing a file into a multidimensional array. I am reverse sorting based on highest score - however when I run the code it currently ignores scores over 100 - can anyone help?

```
scores = []
file = open("hScores.txt","r")
for line in file:
    scores.append(line.strip("\n").split(","))
scores.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
scores.reverse()
print(scores)
```

Comment: You're sorting strings, so they will be sorted lexicographically. If you want them in numerical order, convert them to numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you read from a file is read as a string. You need to convert the numbers to ints before using them to compare as you expect. You can accomplish this by just changing the following line:

```
scores.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings sort the way words sort: "taco" comes before "tesseract" even though "tesseract" is "bigger". You are sorting numbers as if they were strings, so "100" comes before "2" because "1" comes before "2":

```
s = "1,2,3,110,89,108,160,36,19"
sorted(s.split(','))
# ['1', '108', '110', '160', '19', '2', '3', '36', '89']
```

Turn them into numbers and your sort will look more like you expect:

```
s = "1,2,3,110,89,108,160,36,19"
n = map(int, s.split(','))    # map to ints
# now n is an iterator of numbers not strings
sorted(n)
# [1, 2, 3, 19, 36, 89, 108, 110, 160]
# or
sorted(n, reverse=True)
# [160, 110, 108, 89, 36, 19, 3, 2, 1]
```